# Can't connect to RDS using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, amazon-web-services

I'm moving my database to RDS. So I created a dump of the database and uploaded it to RDS.
I can access it from my local machine and from server. It's publicly accessible and security groups are:

```
Inbound - MYSQL/Aurora, 0.0.0.0/0
Outbound - All traffic, 0.0.0.0/0
```

Hibernate config is following:

```
hibernate.connection.username=user
hibernate.connection.password=password
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://rds-endpoint:3306/db
```

Tests that used to work on the server fail with on RDS:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'db.myTable' doesn't exist
```

I tried to remove port or change Inbound to 'All traffic' and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my local database was case-insensitive, while RDS is. So, technically, it's correct that table `db.myTable` doesn't exist as in RDS it's `db.mytable`.